# Errors lines after success build from jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jenkins

I am trying to run build of tests from jenkins

After all the 16 tests success's and I got the message BUILD SUCCESS I got this lines

```
[INFO] Tests run: 16, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  06:15 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-20T12:36:01+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[BE UAT] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files\Selenium\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\mvn.cmd"' mvn compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< Maven:miron >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building miron 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.073 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-20T12:36:02+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkins config

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CWqy.jpg)

Why is that ?

Comment: Where is this: `[BE UAT] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files\Selenium\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\mvn.cmd"' mvn compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"` comming from?

Comment: Its in another folder - not in my eclipse / projects folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the command that's executed:

```
[BE UAT] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files\Selenium\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\mvn.cmd"' mvn compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
```

As you can see, the `cmd.exe` is running `mvn.cmd` with `mvn compile` as arguments. In other words, you're running `mvn mvn compile`.

Edit: if you are using a "classic" freestyle job with an "Invoke top-level Maven targets" step, the Maven goals should **not** contain `mvn`. The Maven command is built from the goals (`clean`, `package`, etc.) and options (`-DsomeOption=someValue`). In freestyle jobs, you can add options either as part of the goals (in which case they should include the `-D` prefix), or separately as part of the options under "Advanced" (in which case you should omit the `-D` prefix).

Comment: What I need to change ? from where its comes mvn mvn compile ?

Comment: That's impossible to say without seeing the part of your pipeline that contains the `cmd` or `mvn` step.

Comment: I am new in all this - how can I pass you the " pipeline that contains the cmd or mvn step." ? where is it ?

Comment: Can you update your question with one or two screenshots from your job configuration that shows the Maven step? Because I think I have an idea what's going wrong, but I'd like to verify my suspicions. I've already updated my answer with what I *think* you're doing wrong.

Comment: I added screenshot please

Comment: It's just as I thought. See the edit to my answer. In short: remove the `mvn` from the goals, as the "Invoke top-level Maven targets" step adds those as arguments to the `mvn` command.

Comment: You also have two Maven build steps. The first one, with no explicit goals, is the one that succeeds. The second one, with the `mvn compile` goals, is the one that fails. I'd remove the first one after you've fixed the second one.